# Display new form in timer tick event

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, timer

I have connected to an SQL Server database and can perform simple CRUD operations. Now I want to make my app show a second `Form` *(a reminder form)* when a person in my database has a birthday today, but nothing happens when I run my app.

EDIT: My reminder form is now showing properly, but when I try to close that form I get this error message:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Form2'.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Form2 forma = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var data = new BirthdayEntities();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tab_Bday.ToList();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);             
        timer.Enabled = true;                       
        timer.Start();                              
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean flag = false;
        IQueryable<Tab_Bday> name;

        using (var data2 = new BirthdayEntities())
        {
            name = (from x in data2.Tab_Bday
                    select x);

            foreach (var x in name)
            {
                if (x.Datum.Day == System.DateTime.Now.Day && x.Datum.Month == System.DateTime.Now.Month)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (flag == true)
            forma.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you setup the timer.

Comment: Where do you create your `Timer`? Can you show the code that sets it up?

Comment: I don't understand what u want from me to show you, I just made this on my main form. Sorry, I'm new and don't understand anything about `timer` and how to set it up... :(

Comment: The enabling of the timer from inside the tick handler looks suspicious. Perhaps it should be enabled elsewhere and disabled in the handler??

Comment: Try this as an example [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/how-to-use-timer-control-in-c)

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I understand now a bit. It's just that error message when I try to close my reminder form. Everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should setup your `Timer`.

```
public void TimerSetup() {
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 1000;     //timer will fire every second
    timer1.Tick += OnTimedEvent;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

Comment: I have tried but complier shows me this error message: 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Elapsed' and no extension method 'Elapsed' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Mensur i Mahir\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Marina\Marina\Form1.cs 29 20 Marina

Comment: There are several timers in .net don't use the one in threading

Comment: It's just that error message when I try to close my reminder form. Everything is working fine...

Comment: @GrantWinney Oops, I forgot that was the threading one... I will fix

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Remember to start and stop the timer.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();

    private void timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
        timer.Stop();
        new Form().ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's just that error message when I try to close my reminder form. Everything is working fine...

Comment: Try ShowDialog() instead of Show(). That will make it modal and stop the main program from continuing until the form is closed. That may fix the error you got when it tried to dispose of the form.

Comment: Why not just create the reminder form when you want to display it? new Form2().ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your reminder form without throwing such an exception when closing it, there are 2 approaches:

```
1. Create new Reminder form every time you want to show it.
2. Add code to `FormClosing` event handler to Cancel the Closing operation and just hide it instead like this:

    public Form1()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     var data = new BirthdayEntities();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tab_Bday.ToList();
     //add this
     forma.FormClosing += forma_FormClosing;
     timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
     timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);                      
     timer.Start();                              
   }
   private void forma_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
     if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing){
         e.Cancel = true;
         forma.Hide();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are accessing the form from withing the timer tick, means after you closed the form 'disposed it' in the timer tick you are trying to access it again so you need to think twice there (I faced the same issue so i just stopped the timer on the form disposed) hope to help some one else quick as this thread is very old.